# Flutter : Dart global variable is output as null

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables

If `formattedDate` is declared as a global variable and `formattedDate` is output in startScreenRecord, the output is good. However, if `formattedDate` is output again in stopScreenRecord, it is output as null. how can I solve this?

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var formattedDate;
  bool recording = false;
  var directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/BackCamera').create(recursive: true);
  bool inProgress = false;

  Future<File> moveFile(File sourceFile, String newPath) async {
    try {

      return await sourceFile.rename(newPath);
    } on FileSystemException catch (e) {
      final newFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);
      await sourceFile.delete();
      return newFile;
    }
  }

  startScreenRecord(bool audio, String formattedDate) async {
    bool start = false;

    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss');
    formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
    print('-------------');
    print(formattedDate);
    print('-------------');
    if (audio) {
      start = await FlutterScreenRecording.startRecordScreenAndAudio(formattedDate);
    } else {
      start = await FlutterScreenRecording.startRecordScreen(formattedDate);
    }
    if (start) {
      setState(() => recording = !recording);
    }
    return start;
  }
  stopScreenRecord() async {
    String path = await FlutterScreenRecording.stopRecordScreen;
    setState(() {
      recording = !recording;
    });
    print("Opening video");
    print(path);
    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    // Move Title.mp4 to Download folder
    final newPath = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/' + "$formattedDate.mp4";
    print(formattedDate);
    print(newPath);
    print(formattedDate.toString());
    final file = await moveFile(File(path), newPath);
    print(file.path);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there are two different variables with the same name `formattedDate` in your code. Let me explain:

1. There is `var formattedDate;` - An instance variable of your `_HomePageState`class, can be referred via `this.formattedDate`.
2. There is the function `startScreenRecord(bool audio, String formattedDate)` with its parameters. So inside the function body, there are both `formattedDate` and `this.formattedDate`, but they are different!

When you are writing

```
var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss');
formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
```

within the function body, you are actually modifying the variable that was passed to the function as a parameter. You are not modifying the instance variable.
What you instead need to do is

```
var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss');
this.formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the global one never used.
The `startScreenRecord` generates its own Date.

The `stopScreenRecord` has no access to the class variable.

If i read the code right. Your functions are outside of the Class. So they have no access to the Class Variables.